sum() of aggregate count()?
I have a query where I pull the domain portion from email addresses out of a column and then count how many users from which domain I have.
How do I get the total count (all users over all domains) in the same query?
select count(regexp_replace( email_id , '^[^@]+@','')) as count, regexp_replace( email_id , '^[^@]+@','') as domain from logins 
  where last_login between '2024-08-06' and '2024-09-06'  
  group by regexp_replace( email_id , '^[^@]+@','') 
  order by count;


ROLLUP
select count(regexp_replace( email_id , '^[^@]+@','')) as count, regexp_replace( email_id , '^[^@]+@','') as domain from logins
  where last_login between '2024-08-06' and '2024-09-06'
  group by rollup(regexp_replace( email_id , '^[^@]+@',''))
  order by count;


Awesome -  thanks! I would never have found that feature in the doco :)

No need to use regular expressions at all (the code below can be found on the fiddle here:
To resolve this, I did the following:
CREATE TABLE logins
(
  email_id TEXT NOT NULL
);

and populate:
INSERT INTO logins VALUES
('blah@domain1.com'),
('blah@domain1.com'),
('blah@domain2.com'),
('bxxx@domain2.com'),  -- note different email address - same domain!
('byyy@domain2.com'),  -- note different email address - same domain!
('blah@domain3.com'),
('blah@domain3.com'),
('blah@domain3.com'),
('blah@domain3.com');

and then we run:
SELECT
SUBSTRING(email_id FROM (POSITION('@' IN email_id) + 1)) AS domain
FROM
logins;
Result:
domain
domain1.com
domain1.com
domain2.com
domain2.com
domain2.com
domain3.com
domain3.com
domain3.com
domain3.com

and then:
SELECT
  SUBSTRING(email_id FROM (POSITION('@' IN email_id) + 1))  AS domain,
  COUNT(email_id) OVER (PARTITION BY SUBSTRING(email_id FROM (POSITION('@' IN email_id) + 1))) AS dom_cnt,
  COUNT(email_id) OVER () AS tot_login_cnt
FROM 
  logins
ORDER BY domain;

Result:
domain      dom_cnt tot_login_cnt
domain1.com       2             9
domain1.com       2             9
domain2.com       3             9
domain2.com       3             9
domain2.com       3             9
domain3.com       4             9
domain3.com       4             9
domain3.com       4             9
domain3.com       4             9

and now we apply the DISTINCT clause:
SELECT DISTINCT
  SUBSTRING(email_id FROM (POSITION('@' IN email_id) + 1))  AS domain,
  COUNT(email_id) OVER (PARTITION BY SUBSTRING(email_id FROM (POSITION('@' IN email_id) + 1))) AS dom_cnt,
  COUNT(email_id) OVER () AS tot_login_cnt
FROM 
  logins
ORDER BY domain;

Result:
domain       dom_cnt tot_login_cnt
domain1.com        2             9
domain2.com        3             9
domain3.com        4             9

Et Voilà! Quite elegant - at last!
Regexes are (very) expensive compared to simple string functions so it is always worth using the latter in preference to the former.
You could create an expression INDEX as follows to enhance performance:
CREATE INDEX logins_email_id_ix ON logins (SUBSTRING (email_id FROM (POSITION('@' IN email_id) + 1)));

You can, of course, do the same for the regex solution:
CREATE INDEX logins_email_id_regex_ix ON logins (regexp_replace( email_id , '^[^@]+@',''));

The fiddle is here and I've run a performance analysis and it would appear that the regex is marginally more performant - however, testing with 9 records on a machine where we don't know what's going on elsewhere is fraught with danger - I would urge you to test with your own data on your own hardware.
